# Cocos2D - NSMutableArray not accessible in ccTouchBegan?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray

First, let's be clear on two things. My English is terrible and I'm pretty new in cocos2d. So sorry and sorry again. :D Now for my question.

I have declared these in a .m (Its a CCscene):

```m
//A mutable array global to my class 

NSMutableArray *arrayBoutons;

//I use this array like this :

LettreBleue *lettre1 = nil;
lettre1 = [LettreBleue construireObjLettre];    
lettre1.position = ccp(80,370);
[self addChild:lettre1];
[arrayBoutons addObject:lettre1];

//The method to register the touch

-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
   [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:kCCMenuTouchPriority swallowsTouches:NO];
}

// The classic TouchBegan in which Im trying to access the value Valeur

-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    // test!
    NSLog(@"Debut test ccTouchBegan4");
    int cptLettres = 0;
    do {
        LettreBleue *unBoutontest=[arrayBoutons objectAtIndex: cptLettres];

        NSLog(unBoutontest.Valeur);

        cptLettres = cptLettres+1;
    } while (cptLettres < 16);
```

The problem is my `arrayBoutons` doesn't seem to keep my data in my `NsMutableArray`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you initialized the NSMutableArray, perhaps in an init method? You need to call something like:

```
arrayBoutons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Then, you need to release it in your dealloc method:

```
[arrayBoutons release];
```

Comment: I do this way too often.  When something is wrong with one of my arrays I almost always check my init to make sure I allocated the array.  This is the most common cause of this problem.